# Visual Studio 6.0 to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

When version VC++ 6.0 application is converted to VC++ 2008, there are [LINK2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z(vs.71).aspx) / [LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(VS.80).aspx) linkage errors.

But the same code compiled and linked and runs without any problem in VC++ 6.0

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Given that those are generic "object not found" linker errors, we're probably going to need some more information on what you're doing. Are the projects building in the right order? Are there other errors in some DLLs that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project is depending on another external library. In VC6, you set the paths properly from Options/Settings, but you missed that in VC2008. That's just a wild guess though..

Answer (score 0):

Jumping from VC6 to VS2008 means dealing with breaking changes in VS2003, VS2005 and VS2008.  Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235427.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177253.aspx).  Just a guess though - need more details.